# Bootstrap4 card-deck - how to have card-deck fits content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-cards

I try to use card-deck with cards inside this way :

- card-deck is centered in a column
- card-deck fits content width (actually, it's always 100% width, width: auto doesn't change anything)
- cards inside the card-deck are left-align

I build a simple codepen for testing, try lot of things but never have the good behaviour...
See https://codepen.io/studio-matavai/pen/zYBeQOX

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Doesn't anyone know how to do this ?

Regards.

----- EDIT -----

[With a picture :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMsWa.jpg)

Comment: what you want to achive???

Comment: Hi, I want the card-deck to fit the content (the cards), not to be full width.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```css
.wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;/*this makes wrapper center*/
    margin-right: auto;/*this makes wrapper center*/
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    }

.card {
padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 240px;
}

.card-body{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  poipoipio
                </div>
            </div>
           
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The card-deck still be 100% full width, it doesn't fit the content

Comment: What do you mean by fitting the content? Could you draw this so that I can know what is the expected result?

Comment: I add a picture to my question

Comment: Updated snip. Also you can set the wrapper as px eg: 900px

Comment: Hi, thks for the reply but I need all cards to have a 240px width.

Comment: So set wrapper as max-width:780px and min-width:780px

Comment: (240+20)*3 = 780 (240 = each card actualwidth, 20 is padding-left plus padding-right) 3 is the number of card

Comment: Of course, but is there a solution for having the card-deck fits the content ? In responsive mode (if 5 card per row, card-deck = 5 cards width, if 4 cards per row, card-deck = 4 cards width....). Actually, it always be 100% width (if I have 4 cards and the viewport is 4.5 cards width, the card-deck is 4.5 cards width, no 4 cards width)

Comment: I am not sure what is the meaning of fit the content, but I have update the snipppet. Is this your expected result?

Comment: Hi, this is what I need, but I try to have the last card not centered but aligned to the left and keep the responsive (so I can't add a special css to the last card because I don't know it in advance if there's 1, 2 3 or 4 cards on the last line).